# What is the return type of localStorage?

Tags: javascript, string, local-storage, arrays

I am setting an localStorage value in byte array format but when I try to get it, it is retrieved as String ?

Why so ?

If so, how can we convert it ?

Help is appreciated !

Comment: Why negative ? Please mention the reason if not post answer

Comment: What do you want after conversion ?

Comment: `window.localStorage` is an object. All item values are stored as strings. So your question really is "how can I convert a string to an array?".

Comment: Basicallly, I am using some encryption algorithms to encrypt and then store. But when I try to retrieve it comes as string.Encrypted value is in byte array format.

Comment: I don no why negative for this qstn.. but this has stopped from posting qstns !

Answer (score 2):

That's just how it's stored: in a `String`.

You can use `JSON.parse(yourStoredValue)`

Comment: Thanks..Let me check                                          :)

Comment: A stored array `localStorage.setItem('array', [1,2,3,4,5,6])` extracted with `localStorage.array` comes out as `"1,2,3,4,5,6"` which is not valid JSON.

Comment: if you have var a = JSON.parse("[1,2,3]"), a will be an array

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store JSON Object - 
Store it

`localStorage.setItem(JSON.stringify({'a': [1, 2, 3]}));`

And you can retrieve it like

`JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("field_name"));`

and if you want to store pure JavaScript codes and execute it later just store it as String and retrieve it like

`eval(localStorage.getItem("field_name"));`

Hope this will help.

Comment: Wouldn't using eval in this situation could open up security problems? What if you localstorage was replaced with malicious code?

Comment: I agree with you that using eval would be harmful since the localStorage is indirectly a user's input. I just used it for better understandings :) as his question was "type of localStorage return"